# How storyboards works under the hood?

Tags: swift, uikit, xcode-storyboard

i wonder how storyboards and class are connected.
I deleted all "main" mentions in target/project and info.plist. and set rootViewController in SceneDelegate:

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dad")
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**my storyBoard:**

[image: storyboard]

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .brown
   }
}
```

**what I get:**

[image: Build app]

**Question is: If I initializing Root ViewController from Storyboard in SceneDelegate. How it knows that background should be brown? I know that I picked ViewController as a Custom Class in Identity Inspector, but How it works under the hood?
like when wrote some code in**

```
 class ViewController
```

**it goes into nib file too? How this interaction between storyboard and class works?**

p.s: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it goes into nib file too?

No. The nib file only has what you put in the storyboard.

> I know that I picked `ViewController` as a Custom Class in Identity Inspector, but How it works under the hood?

When you did this in your code:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dad")
```

the nib is read, and iOS now sees that the VC with the identifier "Dad" has the class `ViewController`, so it makes an instance of that class by calling the [`init(coder:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding/1416145-init) initialiser, so that the things stored in the nib can be decoded, followed by a bunch of other lifecycle methods including but not limited to [`awakeFromNib`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib), `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.

Since `viewDidLoad` of your class is called at some point, the background is set to brown.

Comment: ok I get it, what happens if I delete class in Identity Inspector? It compiles anyway, and which classes instance it shows this time? @Sweeper

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin then it would be `UIViewController`.